# Compare values in table by classname

Tags: javascript, php

I want to compare two different classes with each other. I have multiple rows with the same classname. I am putting out a database table with PHP.

I want to compare the minstock class and the stock class.
If the actual value of stock is lower than the minimum stock I want the background color to change to red.

[image: this is the output]

**This is what I got (MRE)**

```
      <button style="margin-left: 1em" class="btn btn-success" onclick="checkStock()" >Check voorraad</button>
<table border="1px">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>EAN</th>
        <th>Min stock</th>
        <th>stock</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 1</td>
            <td>47230977</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 2</td>
            <td>30237832</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product 3</td>
            <td>48932012</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

function checkStock() {
    var stock = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for(var i = 0; i < stock.length; i++){
        if(stock[i].getAttribute('class') == null || undefined){
            stock[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("minstock")[i].innerHTML > document.getElementsByClassName("stock")[i].innerHTML){
                console.log("stock: ",document.getElementsByClassName("stock")[i].innerHTML)
                stock[i].className = "stock-empty";
            }

        }
    }

}
```

First, I am checking if the "td" tag has a class if not keep the color white I don't want to change any td rows without a classname. If the "td" has a classname compare it. If there is a better way to do this let me know.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58181237/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: _“If there is a better way to do this let me know.”_ - why isn’t your PHP code setting this already on the server side? Unless you manipulate the values dynamically on the client later and therefor need these classes to change dynamically as well, there is not good reason to do this on the client side in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want something like this instead.

Note `if(stock[i].getAttribute('class') == null || undefined){` is invalid JS

```js
function checkStock() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".minstock")].forEach(function(ms) {
    var minStock = +ms.innerText, stock = +ms.closest("td").nextElementSibling.innerText;
    ms.classList.toggle("stock-empty",minStock>stock)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move your logic to php, a quick hint:

```
<?php

$minstock = xxxx;
$stock = xxxx;
$stock_class = 'is-white';

if($stock < $minstock) {
    $stock_class = 'is-red';
}

echo '<td class="'.$stock_class.'">....;
```